# Is it possible to isolate 'rvm upgrade' to single ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade Ruby version. The documentation I initially followed was on RVM:
[Upgrading Rubies](http://rvm.io/rubies/upgrading).

On my machine, I had multiple ruby versions loaded, including

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-pxxx [ i686 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-pxxx [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0   [ i686 ]
```

Wanted to upgrade ruby-2.0, so ran that `rvm upgrade 2.0.0-p0 2.0.0-p247`. The thing is, it then seemed to force upgrade on all of the other versions as well, where I no longer could use commands like `rvm use 1.8` or `rvm use 1.9` without having to upgrade those to the latest `-pxxx` versions.

For reference, **is there a way to isolate this upgrade to one ruby version**, so that for example, when I upgrade 2.0 in future, I don't have to mess around with `ruby-1.9.3-p448` anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what it did was update the info about the latest ruby patches on each version. What you needed to do was `rvm use 1.9.3-pxxx`, where `xxx` is the old ruby version that you already had. If you use only `rvm use 1.9.3` rvm will default to the latest patch of that version

Comment: I'm not sure if this is fully clear to me. So, in this scenario, upgrade 1.9.x, and it should leave 1.8.x and 2.0.x alone. But, in my experience, all 1.x and 2.x versions were prompted for an upgrade.

Comment: They will be prompted for an upgrade, but it's not necessary to upgrade your ruby versions (although it's recommended). The only thing you got to do is, when using `rvm use` command, is specify the full (old) ruby version **with patch** (e.g `rvm use 1.9.3-p125`) and rvm will use it without any warning